# How to mount a compressed ISO image?

Tags: linux, mount, compression, disk-image

I have problem to mount a compressed ([ISZ](http://www.ezbsystems.com/isz/iszspec.txt)) image under Linux, which was created by e.g. [UltraISO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraISO)? I am aware about user-space [fuseiso](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/fuseiso), but it fails to mount these images, as I have reported in [Debian bugtracker](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=580798) (correct me if I ddi something wrong). I ask the community for a help: I need a proved solution to mount these images without decompressing them.

I believe that `CONFIG_ZISOFS` kernel option cannot help, as it refers a special RockRidge extension (per-file compression with [`mkisofs -z`](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/mkisofs) or [`mkzftree`](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/genisoimage)).

Answer (score 1):

ISZ is a proprietary format, at the moment, it looks like there are no linux tools to support it.

daemon tools supports ISZ.

RE fuesiso - it can handle .ISO, .BIN, .MDF, .IMG and .NRG.

Comment: Yes, it is. But the spec is open (another question is "how complete it is"), at least DamonTools was able to implement it, right? You are also right, that fuesiso cannot handle ISZ yet. I look forward for any other solution for Linux.