# creating compressed iso image file

Tags: windows, linux, compression, iso-image, virtual-drive

I want to create a compressed ISO image file and mount that file to one of the virtual drives and access the content (read-only) without worrying about manual decompression/extraction.
For Windows and Linux (Ubuntu) OSes.

Which software tool would be better for this?
Thanks.

Comment: For Windows and Linux (Ubuntu) OSes.

Comment: See the `edit` button? You can always add information to your question later.

Comment: If I remember correctly, there is an option to compress the isos in partimage http://www.partimage.org/Main_Page which is pre installed on most linux systems.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, [UltraISO](http://www.ezbsystems.com/ultraiso/) can create proprietary [ISZ](http://www.ezbsystems.com/isz/iszspec.txt) format images, and [Daemon Tools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/home) can mount them. (related: [How to mount a compressed ISO image?](https://superuser.com/questions/139759/how-to-mount-a-compressed-iso-image))